# Is the following problem NP hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, set-cover, packing

Consider a collection of sets $F=\{F_1,F_2,\dotsc,F_n\}$ over a base set $U=\{e_1,e_2,\dotsc,e_n\}$ where $|F_i|$ $\ll$ $n$ and $e_i \in F_i$, and let $k$ be a positive integer.

The goal is to find another collection of sets $C=\{C_1,C_2,\dotsc,C_m\}$ over $U$ such that each $F_i$ can be written as a union of at most $k$ $(k<<|C|)$ **mutually disjoint** sets in $C$ and also we want $\sum_1^m |C_j|$ to be minimal (i.e., the aggregate number of elements in all sets of $C$ should be as small as possible) .

Note that $F$ has the same size with $U$, but the size of $C$ is uncertain.

Can anyone tell whether the above problem is NP-hard? (set covering？packing？perfect covering）

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what the "problem" is. What is it that you want to answer?

Comment: I have re formatted the problem. Thanks. @Ankur

Comment: Is $k$ given as a part of the problem definition or do you want or is it enough to find $C$ such that the property holds for some $k$? If it is the latter, then take $C=\{ \{e_i\}, i=1...n\}$ and $k = max_i |F_i|$.

Comment: I don't know if this is indeed a known version of Set Cover, but I thought I would suggest a keyword to help you in finding the answer - a cover by mutually disjoint sets is called a "perfect cover".

Comment: Why isn't this problem trivial by setting C={U}?

Comment: Note that one constraint is "no more than k". You just remind me of another constraint since C = {F} is trivial under this statement. I'll add another constraint. Thanks.

Comment: (1) Thank you for correcting the question.  (2) What does “|F|<<n” precisely mean?  I think that you meant to write |F_i| instead of |F|, but even if I assume this, I do not know what exactly “|F_i|<<n” means.  (3) I may be picky, but why did you label [your edit](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/posts/12403/revisions) (revision 10) as “improved formatting”?  It is not the matter of formatting.  It is a correction to the question.

Comment: |F_i|<<n,means each set in F has a size much smaller than n.
Yes, it's a correction, sorry for the confusing label.

Comment: Well, my question was: what is the precise meaning of “much smaller” in this context?

Comment: Beside the precise meaning of “much smaller,” I still have trouble understanding the problem.  As is stated in revision 11, it seems to me that the optimal solution is always C=∅ or C={∅}.  If we add a constraint that C contains at least one nonempty set as an element, then C={{e}} for some element e∈U will be the optimal.

Comment: 1.Just in case that someone may make the assumption that F_i = U. So "|F_i|<<n" is given explicitly. 2.Neither C=∅ nor C={∅} works since in these two cases F_i can't be calculated as a union of sets from C.  Does the statement of problem bring ambiguity? What I want to express is that each F_i can be a union of no more than K mutually disjoint sets from C.

Comment: Please read your own question carefully.  You have never said that C must be chosen so that F_i can be written as a union of sets from C.

Comment: Now I see what you and I interpreted differently.

Comment: I had been misinterpreting “no more than k sets.”  My apologies for that.  But I hope that my edit made the question easier to understand anyway!

Comment: It is trivial if $k\ge n$.

Comment: $k<<n$. And actually in real application, $k$ is a variant rather than a constant. Each $F_i$ has its own value for $k$. @MartinB.

Comment: Can I view the NORMAL SET BASIS problem as a subproblem of the original one?

Comment: It certainly is close to [NORMAL SET BASIS](https://books.google.com/books?id=9NJrCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA32&lpg=PA32&dq=%22NORMAL+SET+BASIS%22&source=bl&ots=6uQ3qhz4Fp&sig=s8U9KbYWYMoxlfGgGhHcrwKs6yg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6xent4f_TAhWB8YMKHXzNDNAQ6AEIIzAA#v=onepage&q=%22NORMAL%20SET%20BASIS%22&f=false).  That problem simply asks whether there exists any solution where $m$ is at most a given $s$ (regardless of $k$ or $\sum_i |C_i|$).  Also that problem has no constraint that $e_i\in F_i$ and $|F|=|U|$.  But it seems likely you can reduce that problem to this one.

Answer (score 2):

**Lemma.** *The problem is NP-hard.*

*Proof sketch.*  We disregard the constraints $|F_i| \ll n = |U|$ in the posted problem, because, for any instance $(F,U,k)$ of the problem, the instance $(F'=F^n,U'=U^n,k)$ obtained by taking the union of $n$ independent copies of $(F,U,k)$ (where the $i$th copy of $F$ uses the $i$th copy of $U$ as its base set) is equivalent, and satisfies the constraint (it has $|F'_i| \le n \ll n^2 = |U'|$).

We give a reduction from 3-SAT.  For presentation, in the first stage of the reduction, we disregard the constraints $e_i \in F_i$ in the posted problem.  In the second stage we describe how to meet those constraints while maintaining correctness of the reduction.

**First stage.** Fix any 3-SAT formula $\phi$.  Assume WLOG that each clause has exactly three literals (each using a different variable). Produce the following instance $(F,U,k)$ of the posted problem, with $k=3$.

Let $n$ be the number of variables in $\phi$.
There are $3n+1$ elements in $U$: one element $t$ (for "true"), and, for each variable $x_i$ in $\phi$, three elements $x_i$, $\overline x_i$, and $f_i$ (for "false").

For each element in $U$ there is a singleton set containing just that element in $F$.  Any solution $C$ therefore includes each of these sets, which contribute their total size $3n+1$ to the cost of $C$.

In addition, for each variable $x_i$ in $\phi$ there is a "variable" set $\{x_i, \overline x_i, f_i, t\}$ in $F$.  For each clause in $\phi$ there is a "clause" set in $F$ consisting of the literals in the clause, and $t$.  For example, the clause $x_1\wedge \overline x_2 \wedge x_3$ yields the set $\{x_1, \overline x_2, x_3, t\}$ in $F$.

**Claim 1.** *The reduction is correct: $\phi$ is satisfiable iff some solution $C$ has cost $\sum_j |C_j| = 5n+1$.*

*(only if)* Suppose $\phi$ is satisfiable. Construct a solution $C$ consisting of the $3n+1$ singleton sets, plus, for each variable $x_i$, the pair consisting of the true literal and $t$.  (E.g., $\{\overline x_i, t\}$ if $x_i$ is false.)  The cost of $C$ is then $5n+1$.

Each variable set $\{x_i, \overline x_i, f_i, t\}$ is the union of three sets: the pair consisting of the true literal and $t$, plus two singleton sets, one for each of the other two elements.  (E.g., $\{\overline x_i, t\}, \{x_i\}, \{f_i\}$.)

Each clause set (e.g. $\{x_1, \overline x_2, x_3, t\}$) is the union of three sets: a pair consisting of $t$ and a true literal, plus two singleton sets, one for each of the other two literals.  (E.g., $\{x_1, t\}, \{\overline x_2\}, \{x_3\}$.)

*(if)* Suppose there is a solution $C$ of size $5n+1$.  The solution must contain the $3n+1$ singleton sets, plus other sets of total size $2n$.

Consider first the $n$ "variable" sets, each of the form $\{x_i, \overline x_i, f_i, t\}$.  The set is the disjoint union of at most three sets in $C$.  Without loss of generality, it is the disjoint union of two singletons and a pair (otherwise, splitting sets in $C$ achieves this without increasing the cost).  Denote the pair $P_i$.  The pairs $P_i$ and $P_j$ for different variables $x_i$ and $x_j$ are distinct, because $P_i$ contains $x_i$, $\overline x_i$, or $f_i$ but $P_j$ does not.  Hence, the sum of the sizes of these pairs is $2n$.  So these pairs are the only non-singleton sets in the solution.

Next consider the "clause" sets, e.g, $\{x_i, \overline x_j, x_k, t\}$.  Each such set must be the union of at most three sets in $C$, that is, up to two singleton sets and at least one pair $P_i$, $P_j$, or $P_k$.  By inspection of the pairs and the clause set, it must be the union of two singletons and one pair, and that pair must be of the form $\{x_i, t\}$ or $\{\overline x_j, t\}$ (a literal and $t$).

Hence, the following assignment satisfies $\phi$: assign true to each variable $x_i$ such that $P_i=\{x_i, t\}$, assign false to each variable $x_i$ such that $P_i=\{\overline x_i, t\}$, and assign the remaining variables arbitrarily.

**Stage 2.** The instance $(F,U,k=3)$ produced above does not satisfy the  constraint $e_i \in F_i$ stated in the problem description.  Fix that shortcoming as follows.  Order the sets $F_i$ and elements $e_i$ in $U$ so that each singleton set corresponds to its element $e_i$.  Let $m$ be the number of clauses in $\phi$, so $|F|=1+4n+m$ and $|U|=1+3n$.

Let $(F', U', k'=4)$ denote the instance obtained as follows. Let $A$ be a set of $2n+2m$ new artificial elements, two for each non-singleton set in $F$. Let $U'=U\cup A$. Let $F'$ contain the singleton sets from $F$, plus, for each non-singleton set $F_i$ in $F$, two sets $F_i\cup \{a_i, a_i'\}$ and $\{a_i,a_i'\}$, where $a_i$ and $a_i'$ are two elements in $A$ chosen uniquely for $F_i$.  Now $|F'|=|U'|=1+5n+2m$ and (with the proper ordering of $F'$ and $U'$) the constraint $e'_i\in F'_i$ is met for each set $F'_i$.

To finish, note that $(F',U',k'=4)$ has a solution of cost $|A|+5n+1$ iff the original instance $(F, U, k=3)$ has a solution of cost $5n+1$.

*(if)*  Given any solution $C$ of cost $5n+1$ for $(F,U,k=3)$, adding the $n+m$ sets $\{a_i, a'_i\}$ (one for each non-singleton $F_i$, so these partition $A$) to $C$ gives a solution to $(F', U', k'=4)$ of cost $|A|+cost(C)=|A|+5n+1$.

*(only if)* Consider any solution $C'$ for $(F', U',k=4)$ of cost $|A|+5n+1$.  Consider any pair of non-singleton sets $F_i\cup\{a_i, a_i'\}$ and $\{a_i, a_i'\}$ in $F'$.  Each is the disjoint union of at most 4 sets in $C'$. By a local-exchange argument, one of these sets is $\{a_i, a_i'\}$ and the rest don't contain $a_i$ or $a_i'$ --- otherwise this property can be achieved by a local modification to the sets, without increasing the cost... (lack of detail here is why I'm calling this a proof *sketch*). So removing the $\{a_i, a_i'\}$ sets from $C'$ gives a solution $C$ for $(F,U,k=3)$ of cost $5n+1$.  $\diamond$